# Algebraic proof of De Morgan's law with three sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

**Given:**

$A'$ $\cup$ $B'$ $\cup$ $C'$ $=$ $(A$ $\cap$ $B$ $\cap$ $C$ $)'$

**Problem:**

Show how the identity above can be proved using two steps of De Morgan's Law along with some other basic set rules (i.e. an algebraic proof).

---

I wasn't aware that De Morgan's Law had multiple steps.  I thought De Morgan's Law was just De Morgan's Law.  Perhaps it means, use two steps used in a direct proof for proving De Morgan's Law?  If that is the case, I find myself a bit lost in determining which two steps to use.

Here is my direct proof of the above.  I'm very new at this, and expect there might be an error or three below.  Any corrections for the direct proof below are welcome in addition to this question.

Let $x\in$$(A'$ $\cup$ $B'$ $\cup$ $C')$ (assumption)

$\Rightarrow$ $x\in$$A'$ $\lor$ $x\in$$B'$ $\lor$ $x\in$$C'$ (by definition of union)

$\Rightarrow$ $x\notin$$A$ $\lor$ $x\notin$$B$ $\lor$ $x\notin$$C$ (by definition of complement)

$\Rightarrow$ $x\notin$$(A$ $\cap$ $B)$ $\lor$ $x\notin$$C$ (by definition of intersection)

$\Rightarrow$ $x\notin$$(A$ $\cap$ $B)$ $\cap$ $C$ (by definition of intersection)

$\Rightarrow$ $x\notin$$(A$ $\cap$ $B$ $\cap$ $C)$ (by associative law)

$\Rightarrow$ $x\in$$(A$ $\cap$ $B$ $\cap$ $C)'$ (by definition of complement)

---

Let $x\in$$(A$ $\cap$ $B$ $\cap$ $C)'$ (assumption)

$\Rightarrow$ $x\notin$$(A$ $\cap$ $B$ $\cap$ $C)$ (by definition of complement)

$\Rightarrow$ $(x\notin$$A$ $\lor$ $x\notin$$B)$ $\cap$ $C$ (by definition of intersection)

$\Rightarrow$ $x\notin$$A$ $\lor$ $x\notin$$B$ $\lor$ $x\notin$$C$ (by definition of intersection)

$\Rightarrow$ $x\in$$A'$ $\lor$ $x\in$$B'$ $\lor$ $x\in$$C'$ (by definition of complement)

$\Rightarrow$ $x\in$$(A'$ $\cup$ $B'$ $\cup$ $C')$ (by definition of union)

---

So I guess it comes down to, if the above is an accurate **direct** proof, what is the **algebraic** proof that uses "two steps" and "some other basic set rules"?

Comment: Wow, answers came in ridiculously fast!  Thanks!

Comment: Yep!  It seems like those answerers know the way to answer your problem!

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate of [Prove$\overline{(A \cap B \cap C)} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \cup \overline{C}$ By Subsets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332860/prove-overlinea-cap-b-cap-c-overlinea-cup-overlineb-cup-overli), but closely related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An algebraic proof is not very hard using basic properties of $\cap,\cup,\bullet'$ and the two sets DeMorgan law.

$$A'\cup B'\cup C'=(A'\cup B')\cup C'=(A\cap B)'\cup C'=((A\cap B)\cap C)'=(A\cap B\cap C)'.$$

We use the fact that $X''=X$, and that $\cap,\cup$ are associative.

Comment: But how does this work out for *sets*?  How does the definition of sets implicit here make such manipulations permissible?

Comment: I don't understand your question Doug.

Comment: As I understand the definition of a (conventional) set, it says that two sets X and Y qualify as equal if and only if X qualifies as a subset of Y and Y qualifies as a subset of X. So, in order to show two sets equal you either have to show A a subset of B and conversely, or at least have some argument that indicates that you could show A a subset of B and conversely.  I only see algebraic manipulations. I don't see any indication that showing one set A as the subset of B, and conversely could in principle happen (and in the books I've read, I haven't seen that). So, how could you do that?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Showing that $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$ is an effective strategy many people use to show that $X=Y$. But it isn't the only strategy. We are allowed to use DeMorgan's Law for two sets:
$$
(X \cap Y)' = X' \cup Y'
$$ in order to prove DeMorgan's Law for three sets.

Comment: @Adriano You've just told *that* you can do so.  I asked about what makes such valid.  Notice that the original post here did try and use the definition.

Comment: @Doug: Note that there was no given definition of what are "basic set rules". The question asked for an algebraic manipulation using the two-step DeMorgan and "basic set rules". The basic set rules are really just the axioms of Boolean algebra, or immediate consequences of those, with regards to the Boolean operations. I still don't feel that I understand your comments, or your inquiry about/objection(?) to this proof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila This comes as a different question.  When you wrote A′∪B′∪C′ and (A′∪B′)∪C′ did you mean the same idea written in two different ways?  What did A′∪B′∪C′ mean?

Comment: @Doug: If $\cup$ wasn't associative, then writing three consecutive unions would be ill-defined. I'm just reminding that $A\cup B\cup C$ can be seen as $(A\cup B)\cup C$, and so we can use the two-step DeMorgan.

Answer (score 4):

The algebraic proof using two steps of de Morgan's would be

$$A' \cup B' \cup C' = (A \cap B)' \cup C' = ((A \cap B) \cap C)'$$

where each step uses $X' \cup Y' = (X \cap Y)'$.

Comment: You also use that $X''=X$.